# TextInput change inside a map function ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, input

I have a problem ,
each item as a TextInput (inside the map function )->

But when I changing the value of 1 input , ALL the values are changing.
any solution ??

Here is my code :

```
          {order.currentShippingContent?.map((content, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={index} style={{marginTop:30}} >
                <View style={{}}
                  <Text style={styles.materialTypeText}>{content.material}</Text>
                  <View>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.InsertAmount}
                      keyboardAppearance="dark"
                      keyboardType="number-pad"
                      placeholder={"type amount"}
                      value={input}
                      onChangeText={(text) => { 
                        setInput(text);
                        if (Number(input) > Number(content.amount)) {
                          return alert("No such amount");
                        }
                        delivery.shippingContent[content.material] =
                          input;
                         
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <Text>/</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.amountText}
                    placeholder={`${content.amount} `}
                    editable={false}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `setInput(text);`. So you have only  `useState` and this value is used in all the TextInput. Your requirement is each of the TextInput should have their own `useState`.

You initialise `useState` with an object where each key and value will represent each `TextInput` and on change of the value from `TextInput` you should change that specific key value in the object

Comment: everything worked , but my goal was only to clear the text input so I added it ,
I've tried to make a state of array , and it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Each item needs its own state its own text input. The easiest way to give them their own state that I can think of is to use a FlatList. First create a function to render items:

```js
const RenderItem = ({ content, index }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <Text style={styles.materialTypeText}>{content.material}</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.InsertAmount}
            keyboardAppearance="dark"
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            placeholder={'type'}
            value={input}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setInput(text);
              // setInput doesnt immediately update input
              // so just use text to avoid dealing with stale state
              if (Number(text || input) > Number(content.amount)) {
                return alert('No such amount');
              }
              delivery.shippingContent[content.material] = input;
            }}
          />
          <Text>/</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.amountText}
            placeholder={`${content.amount} `}
            editable={false}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

And your flatlist:

```js
<FlatList
        data={order.currentShippingContent || []}
        keyExtractor={({ item, index }) => index}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <RenderItem content={item} index={index} delivery={delivery} />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: cant call useState there , and when i declare it at the beggining of the component its the same issue , thank u ... another suggest ?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/U5p65PsIM

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/vy1HOhpbj